# How to display data from firebase database in Ionic 3?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I want to display my database data into ionic view.
here detail data in my database:

```
{firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", username: "jhondoe"}
```

my code in page controller:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase,  FirebaseObjectObservable  } from 'angularfire2/database';

profile : FirebaseObjectObservable<Profile>;


this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
  if(data.email && data.uid){   
    this.afDatabase.object(`profile/${data.uid}`).valueChanges().subscribe(profile => {   
      this.profile = profile;
      console.log(profile);
    });

});
```

view page:

```
<ion-content padding>

  <p>Username: {{ profile?.username | async }}</p>
  <p>First Name: {{ profile?.firstName  | async }}</p>
  <p>Last Name: {{ profile?.LastName  | async }}</p>

</ion-content>
```

but it not work, and display error:

> InvalidPipeArgument: 'John' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Answer (score 1):

`profile` is not a promise/observable since you are setting data after subscription here:

```
 this.afDatabase.object(`profile/${data.uid}`).valueChanges().subscribe(profile => {   
      this.profile = profile;
      console.log(profile);
    });
```

Either declare `profile` as a regular object and remove async:

```
 profile : Profile;
```

Html:

```
<p>Username: {{ profile?.username }}</p>
<p>First Name: {{ profile?.firstName}}</p>
<p>Last Name: {{ profile?.LastName}}</p>
```

**OR**.

declare as an  observable and do not subscribe in ts.

```
 profile : Observable<Profile>;



this.profile = this.afDatabase.object(`profile/${data.uid}`).valueChanges();
```